# AKS Cluster | Failed to query available provider packages | Right version of hashicorp

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, cluster-computing, azure-aks

I'm currently building my terraform plan and it seems that I'm running into issues as soon as I run the following command:

```
terraform init
```

The current main.tf contains this:

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm"{
      resource_group_name = "test"
      storage_account_name = "testaccount"
      container_name = "testc"
      key = "testc.state"
  }
   required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "2.46.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyVaultClientID" {
  name = "AKSClientID"
  key = var.keyvaultID
}

data "azure_key_vault_secret" "keyVaultClientSecret" {
  name = "AKSClientSecret"
  key_vault_id = var.keyvaultID
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "test_cluster" {
  name = var.name
  location = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resourceGroup
  dns_prefix  = ""

  default_node_pool {
    name = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size = "Standard_D2_v2"
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.keyVaultClientID.value
    client_secret = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.keyVaultClientSecret.value
  }

  tags = {
    "Environment" = "Development"
  }
  
}
```

The error message that I get is the following:

```
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azure: provider    
│ registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azure
```

I'm looking at the documentation, and I'm changing the version, but I'm not getting any luck. Does anyone knows what else I can do or what should I change on my main.tf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solve this issue, you will have to add the following inside of the main terraform plan:

```
required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.75.0"
    }
```

If you add it, the issue will never appear again. Also, you might have to run the upgrade command to make sure terraform will be able to handle the new version.